# F# sequence with at least one element

Tags: f#

Beginner in F# here

I want to create a type, which is a sequence of another concrete type (Event) with at least one element. Any other elements can be added anytime later. Normally in C# I would create a class with a private List<Event> and public methods.

But I want to do it with a functional approach and not imitate the C# approach. Or at least try.

My train of thought:

- Let's create a type "of seq" and give it a constructor requiring instance of the Event type

  ```
  type Event = Event of string

  type PublishedEvents = EventList of seq<Event> with
      static member create (event:Event) = EventList(Seq.singleton event)
  ```
- Now let's add an "add" method for adding another optional Event instances

  ```
  type PublishedEvents with
      member this.add(event:Event) = Seq.append this [event]
  ```

But that doesn't work, F# complains that "this" is not compatible with seq<'a>.

So I tried this:

```
type PublishedEvents with
    member this.add (event:Event) : PublishedEvents = EventList(Seq.append this [event])
```

Now it complains that "this" is not compatible with seq<Event>...which is confusing me now since few lines above it says `EventList of seq<Event>` ... so I guess I need to somehow convert `EventList` back to `seq<Event>` so I can then use `Seq.append` ?

```
let convertFunction (eventList:PublishedEvents) : seq<Event> = ???
```

But I have no idea how to do this.

Am I even going the right direction? Is it better for this to mimic a C# class with a backing field? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I propose that you go even more functional and not create members for your types - have it done in your functions. For example this would achieve the same and I would argue it's more idiomatic F#:

```
type Event = Event of string
type PublishedEvents = EventList of Event * Event list

let create e = EventList (e,[])
let add (EventList(head,tail)) e = EventList(e,head::tail)
let convert (EventList(head,tail)) = head::tail |> Seq.ofList

let myNewList = create (Event "e1")
let myUpdatedList = add myNewList (Event "e2")
let sequence = convert myUpdatedList
```

> val sequence : seq = [Event "e2"; Event "e1"]

On the other hand if your aim is to interop with C# your approach would be easier to consume on C# side.

Answer (score 5):

The actual sequence of events is wrapped inside an `EventList` discriminated union case.

You can unwrap it and re-wrap it like this:

```
type PublishedEvents with
    member this.add(event:Event) =
        match this with
        | EventList events -> Seq.append events [event] |> EventList
```

However, I have to question the value of creating this `PublishedEvents` type in the first place, if it's just a single `EventList` case containing a sequence that requires you to wrap and unwrap values repeatedly.

Also, please be aware that this `add` method doesn't change the existing `PublishedEvents`. It creates a new one with a new sequence of events, because of the way that `Seq.append` works, because `seq<'a>` is actually just F#'s name for `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'a>)`.

Furthermore, your approach does not prevent creation of a non-empty event sequence. `EventList` is a public constructor for `PublishedEvents` so you can just write:

```
EventList []
```

A simple way to make the type system enforce a non-empty sequence is this:

```
type NonEmptySeq<'a> = { Head : 'a; Tail : seq<'a> } with
    static member Create (x:'a) = { Head = x; Tail = [] }
    member this.Add x = { this with Tail = Seq.append this.Tail [x] }

let a = NonEmptySeq.Create (Event "A")
let b = a.Add (Event "B")
```

But again, these sequences are immutable. You could do something similar with a C# `List<'a>` if you need mutation. In F# it's called a `ResizeArray<'a>`:

```
type NonEmptyResizeArray<'a> = { Head : 'a; Tail : ResizeArray<'a> } with
    static member Create (x:'a) = { Head = x; Tail = ResizeArray [] }
    member this.Add x = this.Tail.Add x

let a = NonEmptyResizeArray.Create (Event "A")
a.Add (Event "B")
```